# Blender starts with a blurry interface

Tags: interface, windows

[image]

Due to the nature of the model, I can only use the old version 2.67.

When I start the program, I have a problem with the interface, which looks like it is foggy, unlike in newer versions.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: does the interface "work"? can you try running the blender executable from a command window as there may be error messages reported.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>blender
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.67\python

Blender quit

Comment: Operation is normal.
It just looks cloudy on the screen.

Comment: can you try and download the stand alone version (.ZIP) https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.67/ and then expand the archive and run it directly rather than installing it? I just tried it and the screen did not appear strange in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I tried as I said, but it didn't work.

Comment: if it is the same problem with the standalone version then it can really only point to your computer. Check for the latest drivers? Out of interest, what is stopping you using a more up to date version of Blender?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 2.79 it will support your required plugin for which you are trying to install an older version and also won't give blurry effect on the interface.